# Energy Harvesting, Equivalent Capacitance of Battery Formula

Tags: batteries, capacitor, energy-harvesting

So I was reading through TI's datasheet for their BQ25505 [here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq25505.pdf), and came across the following:

> **8.1.2 Storage Element Selection**
>
> In order for the charge management circuitry to protect the storage element from over-charging or discharging,
>   the storage element must be connected to VBAT pin and the system load tied to the VSTOR pin. Many types of
>   elements can be used, such as capacitors, super capacitors or various battery chemistries. A storage element
>   with 100uF equivalent capacitance is required to filter the pulse currents of the PFM switching charger. The
>   equivalent capacitance of a battery can be computed as:
>
> $$C_{EQ} = \frac{2 \ \cdot \ mAHr_{BAT(CHRGD)} \ \cdot \ 3600s/Hr}{V _{BAT(CHRGD)}}$$

I was looking for a bit of enlightenment for this formula.

Assuming a few things, (according to a battery datasheet [here](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/272/micro_932-MIKROE-1120-748894.pdf)) I should have

\$mAHr_{BAT(CHRGD)} = 2,000\$

and

\$V _{BAT(CHRGD)} = 4.2\$

First off, am I correct in assuming \$V_{BAT(CHRGD)}\$ **is** 4.2V and not the nominal 3.7V?

Secondly, **what** is this \$C_{EQ}\$ formula giving me back? **Why** is this \$C_{EQ}\$?

If I get **3,428,571** it doesn't mean anything to me, hence my questions.

Answer (score 1):

The formula gives you the capacitance that store the same amount of energy of a battery (ideally).

\$C_{EQ}\$ has the unit of mF.

So the number means a 3428571 mF (3428 Farad!!) capacitor is needed store the same amount of energy of the battery.